# How do I control my Python program on the local command line using Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a script that uses `requests` library. It is a web scaper that runs for at least 2 days and I don't want to leave my laptop on for that long. So, I wanted to run it on the Cloud but after a lot of trying and reading the documentation, I could not figure out a way to do so.

I just want this: When I run `python my_program.py` it shows the output on my command line but runs it using Google Cloud services. I already have an account and a project with billing enabled. I already installed the GCP CLI tool and can run it successfully.

My free trial has not ended. I have read quickstart guides but as I am fully beginner regarding the cloud, I don't understand some of the terms.

Please, help me

Comment: Are you ssh'ing to the GCP Instance ? If yes, try running the python program there. That way even if you lose connectivity to your local, the script would continue to run in the cloud Instance. If I might have misunderstood you, please elaborate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to setup a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance for that. It's basically a reserved computer/machine where you can run your code. Here's some steps that you should do just to get your program running on the cloud.

1. Spin up a Compute Engine instance
2. Gain access to it (through `ssh`)
3. Throw your code up there.
4. Install any dependencies that you may have for you script.
5. Install `tmux` and start a `tmux` session.
6. Run the script inside that `tmux` session. Depends on your program, you should be able to see some output inside the session.
7. Detach it.

Your code is now executing inside that session.
Feel free to disconnect from the Compute Engine instance now and check back later by attaching to the session after connecting back into your instance.

Comment: I did those steps but when I use the `requests` library, it does not work in the same manner as my local machine. I am getting different results for the same script if I run it both on cloud and locally